# tvOS / iOS - Intercept AudioQueue request to trim ERROR

Tags: ios, avfoundation, tvos, apple-tv

I'm loading a video from a HLS live stream but sometimes I receive this error and then the audio goes out of sync:

```
ERROR:    849: AudioQueue: request to trim 4294723408 + 0 = 4294723408 frames from buffer containing 21504 frames
```

Is there any way to intercept this error so I can at least try to reload the stream or take any other measures?